# How to include text in Share Dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'd like to share a post via facebook AP but I'm facing some issue.
In my original post i have a text and an image.

By using the share button via Facebook it is possible to keep the original text, while that's not true if I use the Send, Feed or Share Dialog. I also tried  using facebook object as reported in the following code, but even in this case I can't figure out how to add text.

Any suggestion?

```
    FB.ui({
    app_id: MY_APP_ID,
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.shares',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object: {
            'og:url': 'www.google.it',
            'og:title': 'myTitle',
            'og:description': 'myDesc',
            'og:image': 'myImg.png'
        }
    })
}, (response) => {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
        alert('Post wasn t published.');
    }
});
```

Comment: What “original text” are you talking about? And what do you want to add? You’re aware that the user must type in the message, you are not allowed to specify it for them, right?

Comment: use the share button on a Facebook's post with text and image, you'll be prompted with a dialog with both the text and image. 
I am not able to achieve that by using fb dialog provided.

Comment: Works fine with the Share dialog, not sure what your issue is.